# "No such module" error in Xcode 8

Tags: ios, swift, xcode8, carthage

I get the "No such module" compilation error in Xcode 8.2.1 in my Swift project.  I use Carthage with two modules: Alamofire and Fuzi.  The `Carthage/Build/iOS` directory exists with the two framework files.  The `Build Settings/Framework Search Paths` points to that directory.  I have embedded the two framework files in `General/Embedded Binaries`.  What am I missing?

Comment: I am able to get past the "No such module" error by adding the Alamofire xcodeproj to the workspace and adding it as a target dependency.

Answer (score 2):

You shouldn't need to embed the libraries; they should be added to **Linked Frameworks and Libraries** underneath the "General/Embedded Binaries" section. Make sure you have the Carthage copy-frameworks script added to your Build Phases.

From the Carthage documentation:

> On your application targets’ “General” settings tab, in the “Linked
>   Frameworks and Libraries” section, drag and drop each framework you
>   want to use from the Carthage/Build folder on disk. On your
>   application targets’ “Build Phases” settings tab, click the “+” icon
>   and choose “New Run Script Phase”. Create a Run Script in which you
>   specify your shell (ex: bin/sh), add the following contents to the
>   script area below the shell:
>
> ```
> /usr/local/bin/carthage copy-frameworks
> ```
>
> and add the paths to the frameworks you want to use under “Input
>   Files”, e.g.:
>
> ```
> $(SRCROOT)/Carthage/Build/iOS/Box.framework
> $(SRCROOT)/Carthage/Build/iOS/Result.framework
> $(SRCROOT)/Carthage/Build/iOS/ReactiveCocoa.framework
> ```
>
> This script works around an App Store submission bug triggered by
>   universal binaries and ensures that necessary bitcode-related files
>   and dSYMs are copied when archiving.

Comment: Didn't work.  I removed the embedded frameworks,  removed references of frameworks from project, did clean build directory, added the frameworks to "Linked Frameworks and Libraries" and added the "Build Phases" script plus input files.  Same error.

Comment: My script is: /usr/local/bin/carthage copy-frameworks ... and carthage exists and is executable at /usr/local/bin ... I specified these input files: $(SRCROOT)/Carthage/Build/iOS/Alamofire.framework and $(SRCROOT)/Carthage/Build/iOS/Fuzi.framework

Answer (score 0):

Firstly you check Carthage installed or not in your machine  like the following command in your terminal

**carthage version**

If carthage is not installed in your machine try the following.

[Download the latest release of Carthage](https://github.com/Carthage/Carthage/releases), and double-click **Carthage.pkg** to run the installer. Click Continue, select a location to install to, then click Continue again, and finally click Install.
Then you can check carthage version.

If you are using existing project then move to project folder like

**cd ~/Path/To/Starter/Project**

Try the following command for update cartfile

**carthage update —platform iOS**

After installation/updation completed then try the following command

**open carthage**

You should see a Finder window pop up that contains two directories: **Build and Checkouts**.
In the Carthage Finder window, navigate into **Build\iOS**. Now, drag Alamofire.framework(for example)  into the **Linked Frameworks and Libraries** section in Xcode:

Next, switch over to Build Phases and add a new **Run Script** build phase. Add the following command:

```
/usr/local/bin/carthage copy-frameworks
```

Click the + under Input Files and add an entry for each framework:

```
$(SRCROOT)/Carthage/Build/iOS/Alamofire.framework
```